# Determine the electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

A loop of wire is put in a changing magnetic field. The magnetic flux through the loop is given by $4t(t+2)$. The loop is connected to a parallel plate capacitor that has a plate separation of  15mm. Determine the electic field between the plates at time $t=3$ s.

Can anyone go through the relevent equations for this question? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$ \mathcal{E} = -{{d\Phi_B} \over dt} = -8t$ (Faraday's law of induction)

$ E = V/d = \mathcal{E}/d = \frac{-8t}{d} = \frac{-8*3}{15\times 10^{-3}} V/m = -1600 V/m$

Comment: I thought giving complete solutions to homework questions was discouraged on this site...

Comment: @Guo Qianyi thanks.Why is the emf equal to the potential difference

Comment: @Guoqianyi is it because you are assuming no resistance